# Can cells and other materials be controlled electromagnetically

Tags: biology, aliens, chemistry, biochemistry, telekinesis

I'm trying to make a creature with a specialized organ that can be controlled telekinetically with cellular precision. Basically the creature would have a specialized organ connected to the brain that sends electromagnetic waves that will send instructions to groups of cells/cells in the telekinetic organ to move, and how can the telekinetic organ cells be powered without connection to blood vessels?

Comment: I am not sure I get your problem. You are describing a nerve and the signal it sends.

Comment: If the organ is a part of the creature's body, why is it not connected to blood vessels? You need to describe the creature in a bit more detail.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining in more detail. What im trying to say, is if it is possible to have a shapeshifting organ that can change shape and move around at the creature's complete control. This organ wont get any blood because it would be detached from the organism and will fly around telekinetically. For example, the creature could shapeshift the organ into a hardened sword then they will make the sword float and move it around like a weapon. Will this be possible by sending electromagnetic waves from another organ which would control each cell's movements?

Comment: Could each cell have tiny antennae that would take radiowaves sent from the organ and use it to control some flagella like organ for movement? What could power the cells? Maybe stored up fats or sugars?

Comment: Giving its cells flagella is not going to make a macroscopic organ capable of flight.

Comment: No, each cell woupd be able to fly around in the air like how bacteria do, these cells wont be connected to each other during flight, so it would be more of a flesh cloud that when it materializes into something, it stops flying.

Comment: I think you're hugely overestimating the amount of force and control flagella provide. Not to mention the little issue of flagella being a mechanism for *swimming*.

Answer (score 3):

### Sounds Like You Want a **Disco Hive**.

You want an organism which can send a blob of its "cells" to fly around. And you're concerned with the following:

1. How can the detached blob move around?
2. How can the main body communicate with the blob?
3. How can the blob get nutrients?

#### The Movement

There are plenty of ways you could do this, but individual cells would be too small.
The smallest flying insects are less than half a millimeter, and even at those scales it becomes difficult to fly at all.
Something the size of a bacteria can't really fly through the air. It can only really drift wherever the air currents take it.

But if you scale up each unit to be composed of many cells, you can get the swarm effect you're after. Think something the size of a gnat.

#### The Communication

Radio wouldn't work, but visible light, or even ir/uv would work great.

You asked in a comment whether each unit might have an antenna to pick up on radio waves. That probably wouldn't work. The problem is that radio waves are fairly big, and the size of the antenna you need to detect electromagnetic radiation is proportional to the wavelength of the light. Very high frequency radio waves have a wavelength around 1mm, so you could technically fit that into something the size of a gnat, but it would be better to use some higher frequency of EM radiation with a smaller wavelength.

Fortunately, the answer to "can creatures biologically communicate with higher frequencies than radio"? is "very yes!" That's what your eyes are for! The wavelength of radiation in the visible spectrum is small enough for the biological "antennas" to fit inside individual cells.

The swarm could be sensitive to certain frequencies of light, and the main body could send directed pulses of light at the swarm to tell it how to move. The swarm might also have some sort of internal communication if individual units can glow. Imagine something that looks like a swarm of fireflies or [pulsing bioluminescent algae](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTDxjOjzm9w).

#### The Feeding

The flying units aren't independent creatures, and lack digestive tracts, so how do they get the fuel needed to fly? Presumably the same way a fight jet does: they get refueled when they land back at base.

Each unit could have a small fat deposit (much like real-world insects do). When the unit lands back on the main body, it couples with the circulatory system, and its fat cells replenish their energy reserves from the blood.
Maybe it has a little mosquito-like needle and punctures special blood cells inside the main body.
The main body could also do something more exotic like perspiring little globules of glucose-saturated 'honey' which gets soaked up by the units when they land.

Whatever the method, each unit should be able to carry around enough energy to go a couple hours before 'recharging'.

#### Bonus Question: What can the swarm do?

The swarm could obviously do the things normal insects can do: deliver venom, collect small amounts of liquid and powder (pollen, etc.).
They could [move small objects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2zqGoE8cYQ).
But having them form up into a sword stretches suspension of disbelief.
Even if they formed into a sword shape, it wouldn't be a very good sword; it would be made of, you know, animal bits.
Poison is the way to go if you want the swarm to be used as a weapon.

But here's a more exotic idea:
How about having them form up into *muscles*?
Give each unit a sturdy 'backbone' that can contract with some amount of force,
and some exotic way of strongly linking together.
Then a group of aligned units could act like a contracting muscle and exert considerable force.
You could do all sorts of interesting stuff with that: dragging larger objects, opening doors, wrapping a swarm around an object to crush it...

---

So in summary: You want your main body to be the home where the individual flying units rest and refuel. Each individual unit would resemble a flying insect. And the main body would control the swarm with visible (or near visible) radiation. The resulting creature would resemble a beehive, albeit one with legs, which flashes like disco lights.

Answer (score 0):

## You need telekinesis to deliver oxygen and take away waste

A high energy organ isn't gonna function without lots of supplies. As such, you need telekinesis to supply the organ with whatever oxygen it needs and to take away any co2 waste.

Comment: Well, then how would oxygen and other materials be moved telekinetically? And are biological anntennae that control flagella possible?

Answer (score 0):

### Fill the organisms with loads of ferrofluid

Start with a huge worm. Now, swap out all the water for a suspension of stabilised magnetic nanoparticles. You now have a magnetic worm. It's not even biologically ludicrous; cells are orders of magnitude bigger than nanoparticles, and iron nanoparticles seem to be relatively non toxic in real life, albeit no one is injecting so many that the subject becomes magnetic....

Manipulate it using magnetic fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your organism to have an organ that can act on its own but also in cooperation with the organism itself and also not be connected to the blood vessels, you might want the organ to behave more like a **parasite**. I suspect that the relationship would be less of one-sided and more of symbiotic if it is basically parasitic relation between them then there can be a certain extent of control it can have on its movement within the body.

When the *organ* is away from the organism, it can communicate telekinetically. But in order to have a very strong cooperation between the two when physically distant from each other, there need to be an *insurance scheme* acting between the two. It could be like that the organ would gaurantee the organism to bring the resources it couldn't itself process but the organism can for itself and for it too. And in turn, the organism would provide the organ with a shelter to grow without stiff competition within its body.